# Swing a sprite in Andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine, modifier

I am developing an app using andengine in which there is an ornament hanging with string. I need to swing it like a pendulum in a loop. I tried to make this happen with rotation modifier inside loop modifier making the center of rotation at the top center point of sprite but it only swing in on direction and then jump straight to the starting point and so on. Following is the code i used.

Is there a ready made modifier for swinging action? of yes, which one, if no, how can i achieve this.

It would be great if you can provide a sample code snippet.

`ornament.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(2, 0, 20, EaseLinear.getInstance())));`

Comment: Any andengine guru out there?

Comment: Its solved guys. Here is how I solved it. I used onModifierFinished method and once swinging at 20 degrees completed I add another rotation modifier to swing it back and did the same thing on backward rotation finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement in this way

```
SequenceEntityModifier seq = new SequenceEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(2, 0, 20, EaseLinear.getInstance()), new RotationModifier(2, 20, 0, EaseLinear.getInstance()));
        ornament.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(seq));
```

Try this